# When does an inventor first learn who is her patent examiner?

Tags: patent-applications, examiner

After a patent is filed, the USPTO typically mails back the filing receipt before assigning the patent to an examiner.
How long does it typically take to assign an examiner?
When/how does the inventor first learn who the examiner is?

Comment: After your filing has been accepted and reviewed an examiner is assigned. Using Public Pair at the USPTO site you can get the information by a search for the application number

Comment: @Moti I encourage you to post your comment as an answer.